# Authentication Problem

Tags: 11.10

I recently installed version 11.10. While adding a user, it wants me to include an authenication password. I thought I knew it and put it in but it keeps on rejecting. I even tried other alternative passwords which I generally use. No luck there too.

Is there any way I can retrieve what it was that I signed up with when I downloaded and installed 11.10? Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your computer on.

Press ESC at the grub prompt.

Press `e` for edit.

Select the line that begins with `kernel ………`

Press the key `e` to edit

Go to the very end of the line. Add `rw init=/bin/bash` to it.

Press enter, then press `b` to boot your system.

Your system will boot up to a password less root shell.

Set your password:

```
passwd <yourusername>
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```